# get new item for each users

Tags: php, algorithm, forum

I have many objects(Entity). For example "news", "blogs", 'comments';
I need to show registered user how much "news" or "blog" is NEW for him;

Now, i create a relation many-to-many; For example "users-news-reader" which contains fields : id, userId, newsId;
if the relation for "news" exists then this "news" has already been read, i.e. a count of "news" is a count of NEW "news" for current user

So, in this method i have many tables for many-to-many relation. 
how can I make it more beautiful and correct?

Comment: Store the last time the user viewed stuff then just select stuff where it was added after that time. Saves a lot of mapping tables

Comment: it seems this used in forum engines.. Thanks! 
but may have more solutions?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in SQL.

Tables:

```
user_logons (username,logontime datetime)
news (newsitem,newstime datetime)
user_news (newsitem,username)
```

SQL

```
SELECT count(*),newsitem FROM news LEFT JOIN user_news ON user_news.newsitem=news.newsitem WHERE newstime > 
(SELECT logontime FROM user_logons ORDER BY logontime DESC LIMIT 1) 
AND user_news.username IS NULL
```

Should work.  This will only show new news since the last logon which has not been viewed by the user.  You can adapt this for blogs too.  This will also count the number of new articles.  Sadly, no time to test. try sqlfiddle.com